# Where to download driver for Sierra MC8305 for Windows 10?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, gsm, sim

Where to download driver for Sierra Wireless MC8305 (3G WWAN) for Windows 10?

The `FTS_SierraWirelessMC8305WWANDriver_Build3948_1105401.zip` downloaded from Fujitsu Support for Windows 8.1 won't install. And Microsoft generic driver does not work with all SIM cards (the one I have problem with cannot login into GSM network at all).

Comment: You will have to contact `Sierra Wireless` for a driver compatible with Windows 10 in that case.

Comment: So I send an email to source@sierrawireless.com

Comment: Got answer from SW: "We don’t provide laptop drivers for our WWAN parts. The reason is that the firmware / drivers are specific to the laptop OEM, and they control which combinations of laptop / driver / OS that they choose to support. For instance, a driver for HP would not play nicely with the VID/PID for a Dell card, even if they are the same module." I'm giving up, going back to Windows 7.